# context not defined, what is the best way to handle this

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the block of code from  [this link](https://protocoderspoint.com/flutter-todo-app-with-nodejs-mongodb-at-backend/)  in down below. I am new to fluuter, and what  I see is the word `context` is not defined anywhere. yet

```
 if(jsonResponse['status']){
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>SignInPage()));
```

This part has it at the top without any problems.. I am new to flutter,

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:velocity_x/velocity_x.dart';
import 'applogo.dart';
import 'loginPage.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'config.dart';

class Registration extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegistrationState createState() => _RegistrationState();
}

class _RegistrationState extends State<Registration> {

  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  bool _isNotValidate = false;

  void registerUser() async{
    if(emailController.text.isNotEmpty && passwordController.text.isNotEmpty){

      var regBody = {
        "email":emailController.text,
        "password":passwordController.text
      };

      var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(registration),
      headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"},
      body: jsonEncode(regBody)
      );

      var jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);

      print(jsonResponse['status']);

      if(jsonResponse['status']){
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>SignInPage()));
      }else{
        print("SomeThing Went Wrong");
      }
    }else{
      setState(() {
        _isNotValidate = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [const Color(0XFFF95A3B),const Color(0XFFF96713)],
                begin: FractionalOffset.topLeft,
                end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                stops: [0.0,0.8],
                tileMode: TileMode.mirror
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CommonLogo(),
                  HeightBox(10),
                  "CREATE YOUR ACCOUNT".text.size(22).yellow100.make(),
                  TextField(
                    controller: emailController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        errorText: _isNotValidate ? "Enter Proper Info" : null,
                        hintText: "Email",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)))),
                  ).p4().px24(),
                  TextField(
                    controller: passwordController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.copy),onPressed: (){
                          final data = ClipboardData(text: passwordController.text);
                          Clipboard.setData(data);
                        },),
                        prefixIcon: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.password),onPressed: (){
                          String passGen =  generatePassword();
                          passwordController.text = passGen;
                          setState(() {

                          });
                        },),
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        errorText: _isNotValidate ? "Enter Proper Info" : null,
                        hintText: "Password",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)))),
                  ).p4().px24(),
                  HStack([
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: ()=>{
                        registerUser()
                      },
                        child: VxBox(child: "Register".text.white.makeCentered().p16()).green600.roundedLg.make().px16().py16(),
                    ),
                  ]),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){
                      print("Sign In");
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>SignInPage()));
                    },
                    child: HStack([
                      "Already Registered?".text.make(),
                      " Sign In".text.white.make()
                    ]).centered(),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

String generatePassword() {
  String upper = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  String lower = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  String numbers = '1234567890';
  String symbols = '!@#\$%^&*()<>,./';

  String password = '';

  int passLength = 20;

  String seed = upper + lower + numbers + symbols;

  List<String> list = seed.split('').toList();

  Random rand = Random();

  for (int i = 0; i < passLength; i++) {
    int index = rand.nextInt(list.length);
    password += list[index];
  }
  return password;
}
```

I tried to do the same, it says `context` is not defined. Do I need to pass the `context` from  `Widget build(BuildContext context) {` as a parameter to my `registerNext()` function's caller. Also what is this `context` for specifically if I am navigating to a new page already ?

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'registerTwo.dart';
import 'package:jwt_decoder/jwt_decoder.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:velocity_x/velocity_x.dart';




class RegistrationPage extends StatelessWidget {

  TextEditingController nameController      = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController lastnameController  = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController phoneNumController  = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController     = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController  = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController repassController    = TextEditingController();

  void registerNext() {
    var inf = {
      "name"     : nameController.text,
      "lastname" : lastnameController.text,
      "phone"    : phoneNumController.text,
      "email"    : emailController.text,

    };
    String emailTxt = emailController.text;
    log("data $emailTxt");
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>ProfilePage(info: inf)));
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stateless widgets doesn't have context - they get it only as parameter in build function.

So to use context in widget's functions you need to use `State` of `StatefulWidget` as in your first code example.

Or you can send a context as parameter to necessary functions from `build` function on calling. For example

```
void registerNext(BuildContext context) {
...
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  registerNext(context);
  return Container();
}
```

but in this case all your widget fields (as nameController and others) must be final. So in your situation it's better to simply use stateFul widget and make your staff in state of this stateFul widget.

---

**Update** with answer on question about navigator.

You need to send context to navigator because all routes store in app's context and navigator may change actual routing in actual context.

You can read more about navigator here - https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation

As alternative you can use static context getter by creating global navigation key.

1. Create a global key

```
/// Somewhere in lib folder

/// Key for navigation without requiring context
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

/// Key getter
GlobalKey<NavigatorState> get key => _navKey;

/// Current context getter
BuildContext? get actualContext {
  return _navKey.currentContext;
}
```

2. Pass it to Application

```
final class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'App',

        /// Key for navigation without requiring context
        navigatorKey: NavPro.key,

        /// other parameters
    );
  }
}
```

3. Use it where you need. But you need to check if it's null before use it

```
if(actualContext != null) Navigator.push(actualContext!, someRoute);
```

Also you can use special navigation packages as [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route). It also can provide static context.

Comment: Stateless *and* Stateful widgets get their context from build.  Not sure why you distinguished them.

Comment: Sorry, I mean state of stateful widget. Updated comment

Comment: okey, well said. any reason why I need to pass context to Navigator Object ?

Comment: Added information about navigator